# Trigger Work Flow Based on SharePoint List Column Value Update

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow

I have a SharePoint Online List with cases that staff have to review on a regular basis. When a case review is done staff select 'Complete' from a drop-down in the field labeled Case Review. I am trying to create a data flow that sends an email to a specific group when an item has that Case Review field marked 'Complete'. I have looked through templates but cannot figure out how to specify that when a field is changed to a specific value an email needs to be sent. I am very new to SharePoint Online. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS flow, below is what you need. I have used trigger point when item is created or modified, you can use only modified also. Instead of using Status Column you can use 'Case Review' column

[image]

Comment: this will trigger again when anything is changed, if the status is still "complete"

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the MS flow cannot be triggered on a specific filed. As a workaround, you could add a condition under the trigger "when an item is create or modified". Something like this:

[image]